# MonoGame Pipeline tool output going to wrong directory when built by Visual Studio

Tags: monogame

I'm using VS2015 Professional and MonoGame 3.4.0.456.

I have a Content project and a Fractals project. The Content project contains a `Content.mgcb` file with the output directory set to `../Fractals/Content`.

When I build the content from the Pipeline tool itself, the output goes to the correct directory, i.e. `<solution>/Fractals/Content`. However, when it is built by Visual Studio, the output goes to `<solution>/Content/Content/bin/Windows`.

This means I have to manually build the content whenever it changes.

Is there a way to get the output to go to the correct directory when the content project is built by VS?

Please note - I posted this on the MonoGame forum [here](http://community.monogame.net/t/pipeline-tool-output-going-to-wrong-directory-when-built-by-visual-studio/6264) a few days ago, but haven't had any replies.  Apologies if this is disapproved of.

Comment: The Pipeline tool is still new and a bit buggy. Try [the latest development build (v3.5)](http://teamcity.monogame.net/repository/download/MonoGame_DevelopWin/latest.lastSuccessful/Windows/MonoGameSetup.exe?guest=1) instead of 3.4. It's got a number of bug fixes, but I'm not sure if this is one of them.